# Triple external monitor on 13" Macbook Pro 2018

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro

I posted this on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404265/triple-external-monitor-on-13-macbook-pro-2018) but it seems appropriate to ask here too.

I've recently been given a 13" Macbook Pro 2018 by work so that I can work from home. Just to note I am completely new to MacOS, but have a lot of sysadmin experience on other platforms.

I have a triple monitor set up with my Windows PC and I was hoping to use this with the new Macbook. But I looked online and it seems that this model is officially limited to two external monitors. However The limit is for two 4k monitors, and I want three 1080p which is a lower total pixel count than even one 4k screen so the MBP definitely has the power required for this.

Also I don't need the built-in display as the MBP will be tucked away. Clearly the MBP can do three displays if we include the built-in one, so is there a way to redirect that to an external screen? Is there an official or unofficial way to make this work? Would using a thunderbolt based adapter allow more bandwidth so more screens? I've seen reports of USB3 (not type C) display adapters that can bypass this restriction. Or there's this https://github.com/FD-/RPiPlay that would involve using a Raspberry Pi as an airplay receiver and using that as the third screen.